# Как скрыть лишнюю часть анимации

Tags: html, css

Как скрыть  вылезающую часть анимации при повороте ? Когда квадрат на ребро становится , он выходит за размер секции

```css
@keyframes rotate {
  0%   {transform:rotate(0deg);}
  100% {transform:rotate(360deg);}
}

.header__square-pic {
  height: 568px;
  width: 568px;
  background-color: #2f80ed;
 position: absolute;
  right: 0px;
  top:64px;
  z-index: 0;
  animation: rotate 20s infinite  linear;}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: https://codepen.io/camobap6/pen/eYpqdjN. Когда квадрат на ребро становится , справа за ширину страницы вылезает угол (на скриншоте граница серая)

Comment: Не , у меня по заданию сделать именно rotate и что бы скрылось.

Comment: не , там ничего нет )  просто задание такое задали =)

Comment: Да вроде ничего не мешает.Я извиняюсь , но я не понял как обернуть и overflow поставить. Не сталкивался еще с таким.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Во-первых, классы нельзя называть только цифрами.
Во-вторых, если нужно срезать что-то, то для родительского блока нужно указать размеры и overflow.

```css
@keyframes rotate {
  0%   {transform:rotate(0deg);}
  100% {transform:rotate(360deg);}
}

.one {
  width: 1000px;
  height:900px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.header__square-pic {
  height: 568px;
  width: 568px;
  background-color: #2f80ed;
 position: absolute;
  right: 0px;
  top:64px;
  z-index: 0;
  animation: rotate 20s infinite  linear;
}
```

```html
<section class="one">
<div class="header__square-pic"></div>
</section>
```

Comment: Благодарю. То что нужно.